# How to create Taxonomy Terms child views

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I want to display taxonomy terms list.

I have a taxonomy named "Categories", I want to make a views page where all terms displays which has no childs. If user clicks on any listed terms then next level of respective terms displays and so on. If a term doesn't have any child terms then it should displays post of related term. My content type posts will be attached to last level of taxonomy.

Is it possible using Drupal 7 Views? Help me please.

Comment: Hello welcome to drupal.stackexchange! What research have you done in this area for module(s) which may help you solve your problem ?

Comment: No module solved my problem. I created a custom select list as category in taxonomy and in the views I filter it according to select list value and listed all terms I want and its fixed :)